# MSIX package can install but won't update

Tags: auto-update, msix

## Use case

I can install the MSIX package. It detects an update but when I'm trying to update a justed packaged MSIX package. When I release I get the following error:

## Error

`App installation failed with error message: error 0x8007000D: Opening the package from location Package.msix failed. (0x8007000d)`

## Source:

- https://github.com/microsoft/msix-packaging/blob/master/src/inc/public/MsixErrors.hpp#L31 (is the spot where the error is defined)
- https://github.com/microsoft/msix-packaging/blob/c8af99506ffd0c1513fad39cdadfac281723c3e3/src/msix/pack/AppxBundleWriter.cpp#L212 (is the spot where it throws the error)

## Question

What can I do? When I google on the 0x8007000D I'm getting the MSIX error that the data is invalid. How can I see what part of the data is invalid?

## Log

`Note: The URL doesn't work. I renamed it because installing works from that download location`

```
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021] Log File is located under: C:\Users\StuiterSlurf\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TempState\AILog.txt
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} ConvertVersionToUINT64(String) -> Version [2814750931222528]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} ConvertVersionToUINT64(String) -> Version [2814750931288064]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} ConvertVersionToUINT64(String) -> Version [2814751014977536]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} ConvertVersionToUINT64(String) -> Version [2814751015043072]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} ConvertVersionToUINT64(String) -> Version [2814751096504320]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} ConvertVersionToUINT64(String) -> Version [2814751096569856]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} ConvertVersionToUINT64(String) -> Version [2814751232425984]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} App::OnFileActivated: Activated via file
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} RegisterBackgroundTask -> Checking if  Background Task is already registered.
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} RegisterBackgroundTask ->  Background Task is already registered.
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} RegisterBackgroundTask -> Checking if  Background Task is already registered.
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} RegisterBackgroundTask ->  Background Task is already registered.
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} ConvertVersionToUINT64(PackageVersion) -> Version [281544525414400]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} GoToState -> WindowButtonsPresentState
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} Activated with File contract.
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} Argument is a File. Path: [C:\Users\StuiterSlurf\OneDrive - StuiterApp\Desktop\Package.appinstaller]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} Setting launch intent to FILE_OR_HTTP_WITHOUT_MSAPPINSTALLER_INSTALL
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} GoToState -> LoadingState
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppsInfo->CreateAsync, URI: [file:///C:/Users/StuiterSlurf/OneDrive%20-%20StuiterApp/Desktop/Package.appinstaller]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppsInfo, File Type: [AppInstaller]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppDataSource::CreateAsync
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppInstaller XML content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<AppInstaller xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2018" Version="123.2.0.19437" Uri="https://StuiterAppmsixtest.blob.core.windows.net/fast/Package.appinstaller">

  <MainPackage Name="StuiterAppDesktopFAST" Version="123.2.0.19437" Publisher="CN=StuiterApp B.V., OU=IT, O=StuiterApp B.V., L=Enschede, C=NL" Uri="https://StuiterAppmsixtest.blob.core.windows.net/fast/Package.msix" ProcessorArchitecture="x64" />

  <UpdateSettings>

    <OnLaunch HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0" UpdateBlocksActivation="true" ShowPrompt="true" />

    <AutomaticBackgroundTask />

    <ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion>true</ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion>

  </UpdateSettings>

</AppInstaller>
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppInstallerExtension::CreateAsync -> .appinstaller URI is [file:///C:/Users/StuiterSlurf/OneDrive%20-%20StuiterApp/Desktop/Package.appinstaller]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppDataSource::CreateAsync
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppInstaller XML content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<AppInstaller xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2018" Version="123.2.0.19437" Uri="https://StuiterAppmsixtest.blob.core.windows.net/fast/Package.appinstaller">

  <MainPackage Name="StuiterAppDesktopFAST" Version="123.2.0.19437" Publisher="CN=StuiterApp B.V., OU=IT, O=StuiterApp B.V., L=Enschede, C=NL" Uri="https://StuiterAppmsixtest.blob.core.windows.net/fast/Package.msix" ProcessorArchitecture="x64" />

  <UpdateSettings>

    <OnLaunch HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0" UpdateBlocksActivation="true" ShowPrompt="true" />

    <AutomaticBackgroundTask />

    <ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion>true</ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion>

  </UpdateSettings>

</AppInstaller>
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppInstallerExtension -> Retrieving the redirection URI from the XML
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppInstallerURIRedirect, Previous URI: [file:///C:/Users/StuiterSlurf/OneDrive%20-%20StuiterApp/Desktop/Package.appinstaller], Redirect URI: [https://StuiterAppmsixtest.blob.core.windows.net/fast/Package.appinstaller]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppDataSource::CreateAsync
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppInstaller XML content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<AppInstaller xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2018" Version="123.2.0.19442" Uri="https://StuiterAppmsixtest.blob.core.windows.net/fast/Package.appinstaller">

  <MainPackage Name="StuiterAppDesktopFAST" Version="123.2.0.19442" Publisher="CN=StuiterApp B.V., OU=IT, O=StuiterApp B.V., L=Enschede, C=NL" Uri="https://StuiterAppmsixtest.blob.core.windows.net/fast/Package.msix" ProcessorArchitecture="x64" />

  <UpdateSettings>

    <OnLaunch HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0" UpdateBlocksActivation="true" ShowPrompt="true" />

    <AutomaticBackgroundTask />

    <ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion>true</ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion>

  </UpdateSettings>

</AppInstaller>
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppInstallerExtension -> Retrieving the redirection URI from the XML
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppInstallerExtension -> Populating primary package information
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppInstaller - Primary Package:
    Name: [StuiterAppDesktopFAST]
    Uri: [https://StuiterAppmsixtest.blob.core.windows.net/fast/Package.msix]
    Publisher: [CN=StuiterApp B.V., OU=IT, O=StuiterApp B.V., L=Enschede, C=NL]
    Version: [123.2.0.19442]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppDataSource::CreateAsync
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:48 2021]{10812d} AppPackageInfo::CreateAsync -> Populating package info
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Manifest Info -> Package Name is: StuiterAppDesktopFAST
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Manifest Info -> Package Full Name is: StuiterAppDesktopFAST_123.2.0.19442_x64__7a4m9c63373k2
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Manifest Info -> Package Family Name is: StuiterAppDesktopFAST_7a4m9c63373k2
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Manifest Info -> Publisher is: CN=StuiterApp B.V., OU=IT, O=StuiterApp B.V., L=Enschede, C=NL
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Manifest Info -> Processor architecture is: x64
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Manifest Info -> Package Version is: 123.2.0.19442
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Manifest Info -> App DisplayName is: StuiterApp Desktop  - Production (Fast Ring)
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Manifest Info -> App PublisherDisplayName  is: StuiterApp B.V.
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Manifest Info -> App Logo  is: Images\PROD-FAST\StoreLogo.png
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Manifest Info -> First Application AppUserModelId StuiterAppDesktopFAST_7a4m9c63373k2!App 
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Manifest Info -> Populating package dependencies
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Manifest Info -> Package is Not a Modification Package
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Signature Info -> Cert Subject: [NL, Enschede, StuiterApp B.V., IT, StuiterApp B.V.]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Signature Info -> DoesSignatureCertContainStoreEKU returned FALSE
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Signature Info -> IsTrustedChain (isMicrosoftTrustedChain = False) returned TRUE
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Signature Info for Package -> Package Cert Origin: [TRUSTED] Package Cert Subject: [NL, Enschede, StuiterApp B.V., IT, StuiterApp B.V.]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Retrieving installed application package for user with package name: [StuiterAppDesktopFAST] and publisher name: [CN=StuiterApp B.V., OU=IT, O=StuiterApp B.V., L=Enschede, C=NL] with package types: [33]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Found package [StuiterAppDesktopFAST_123.2.0.19437_x64__7a4m9c63373k2] but VerifyIsOK returned false (ignoring)
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} ConvertVersionToUINT64(PackageVersion) -> Version [34621430725364717]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Retrieving installed application package for user with package name: [StuiterAppDesktopFAST] and publisher name: [CN=StuiterApp B.V., OU=IT, O=StuiterApp B.V., L=Enschede, C=NL] with package types: [8]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} PopulateAppInstallationStatus -> App Already Installed! App Package Full Name: StuiterAppDesktopFAST_123.2.0.19437_x64__7a4m9c63373k2
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Installation Status [Package] -> Older version of the App is already installed
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} AppInstallerExtension -> Populating optional packages information
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} AppInstallerExtension -> Populating related packages information
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} AppInstallerExtension -> Populating optional and related packages that should be installed
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} AppInstallerExtension -> Populating Overall Installation Status
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Installation Status: INSTALLED_OLDER_VERSION
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Overall AppInstallerExtension Installation Status: 1
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} AppInstallerExtension -> Populating dependency packages information
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} AppInstaller - ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion XML Value: [true]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} AppInstaller - ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion setting: [True]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} AppInstaller - xmlns: [[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} AppInstaller - UpdateBlocksActivation XML Value: [true]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} AppInstaller - UpdateBlocksActivation setting: [True]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} AppInstaller - UpdateSettings XML node found.
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} AppsInfo -> PopulateFromAppInstallerExtensionAsync
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Already Installed App Package Version: 123.2.0.19437
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Signature Info Overall -> Overall Cert Origin: [TRUSTED] Cert Subject: [NL, Enschede, StuiterApp B.V., IT, StuiterApp B.V.]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} PopulateAppInstallerUpdateAvailabilityAsync
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Retrieving installed application package for user with package name: [StuiterAppDesktopFAST] and publisher name: [CN=StuiterApp B.V., OU=IT, O=StuiterApp B.V., L=Enschede, C=NL] with package types: [33]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} Found package [StuiterAppDesktopFAST_123.2.0.19437_x64__7a4m9c63373k2] but VerifyIsOK returned false (ignoring)
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:49 2021]{10812d} PopulateAppInstallerUpdateAvailabilityAsync -> location of already installed .appinstaller file is: [https://StuiterAppmsixtest.blob.core.windows.net/fast/Package.appinstaller]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} PopulateAppInstallerUpdateAvailabilityAsync -> m_appInstallerUpdateAvailability is Error
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} m_appInstallationStatus is INSTALLED_OLDER_VERSION but m_appInstallerUpdateAvailability is Error
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} This indicates an error on the IT admin where the user had installed an older version of this app that doesn't link to the new .appinstaller file
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} GoToState -> LoadedState
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} GoToState -> DisplayAppsInfoState
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} DisplayAppsInfoState -> DisplayAppsInfoSetDefaultsHelper
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} GetIsSelfElevatedAppServiceClientSupported -> True
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} DisplayAppsInfoState -> DisplayAppsInfoTopPartHelper
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} GetIsRunningOn10X -> False
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} GetIsRunningOn10X -> False
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} GetIsRunningOn10X -> False
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} GetIsRunningOn10X -> False
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} GetIsRunningOn10X -> False
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} GetIsRunningOn10X -> False
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} GetIsSelfElevatedAppServiceClientSupported -> True
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} DisplayAppsInfoState -> DisplayAppsInfoBottomPartForReadyStateHelper
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} mainContentContainer height: 228.000000
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} bottomContentContainer height: 103.000000
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} mainContentContainer height: 228.000000
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:50 2021]{10812d} bottomContentContainer height: 103.000000
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} MainPage -> Update button was clicked
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} GetIsUserConsentOnInstallRequired -> False
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} PackageDependencyInstaller -> Missing Dependency Packages count: 0
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} PackageDependencyInstaller -> Required missing dependency packages count: 0
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} PackageDependencyInstaller -> Required missing external dependencies count: 0
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} GoToState -> GoToPreparingDeploymentState
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} MainPage -> Preparing for Main App Install
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} MainPage -> Installing Main App
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} GoToState -> GoToDeployingState
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} StartInstallOperation -> URI: file:///C:/Users/StuiterSlurf/OneDrive%20-%20StuiterApp/Desktop/Package.appinstaller
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} GetIsSelfElevatedAppServiceClientSupported -> True
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} Deploying AppInstaller extension file
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} GetIsAddPackageByAppInstallerOptionsLimitToExistingPackagesEnumNameValuePresent -> True
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:52 2021]{10812d} [RequestAddPackageByAppInstallerFileAsync] -> With ForceTargetAppShutdown
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:53 2021]{10812d} DeploymentCompletionCallback
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:53 2021]{10812d} DeploymentCompletionCallback -> Install Operation Failed. Error Code: 0x8007000d, Extended Error Code: 0x8007000d
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:53 2021]{10812d} DeploymentCompletionCallback -> fallbackErrorText: error 0x8007000D: Opening the package from location Package.msix failed. (0x8007000d)
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:53 2021]{10812d} GoToState -> DeploymentErrorState
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:53 2021]{10812d} Toaster->ShowToast [Error]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:53 2021]{10812d} GetEncodedXmlValue -> XML: [StuiterApp Desktop  - Production (Fast Ring) installation failed], Encoded XML: [StuiterApp Desktop  - Production (Fast Ring) installation failed]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:53 2021]{10812d} GetEncodedXmlValue -> XML: [App installation failed with error message: error 0x8007000D: Opening the package from location Package.msix failed. (0x8007000d)], Encoded XML: [App installation failed with error message: error 0x8007000D: Opening the package from location Package.msix failed. (0x8007000d)]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:53 2021]{10812d} Toaster->Toast Error Data [<toast launch="App Installer" activationType="background" duration ="short"><visual><binding template = "ToastGeneric"><text>StuiterApp Desktop  - Production (Fast Ring) installation failed</text><text>App installation failed with error message: error 0x8007000D: Opening the package from location Package.msix failed. (0x8007000d)</text></binding></visual></toast>]
[Tue Oct 26 13:36:53 2021]{10812d} ReplaceSensitiveStrings 
Old message: [App installation failed with error message: error 0x8007000D: Opening the package from location Package.msix failed. (0x8007000d)]
Replace message:[App installation failed with error message: error 0x8007000D: Opening the package from location Package.msix failed. (0x8007000d)]
```